# How to route from nodejs to locally uploaded image file mysql

Tags: node.js

In nodejs, there is an image uploaded file using multi. I want to print this image path in mysql to client view.But I don't know what to do. Please let me know.

controller

```
export const getBoardCreate = (req, res) =>
  res.render("boardCreate", {
    homeName: "watchingame",
    pageName: "boardCreate",
    routers
  });
export const postBoardCreate = (req, res) => {
  try {
    let sql =
      "insert into board(folder,title,content, nicName,writeDate,views,comments) values(?,?,?,1,now(),0,0)";
    dbConnection.query(
      sql,
      [req.body.folder, req.body.title, req.body.content],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          const {
            body: { folder, title, content },
            file
          } = req;
          console.log(file);
        }
      }
    );
    res.redirect(`/board${routers.boardDetail(result.insertId)}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

view

```
extends layouts/layout
block content
    form(method="post" action=`/board${routers.boardCreate}` enctype="multipart/form-data")
        select(name="folder")
            option(value="select") select
            option(value="wg") ~
            option(value="news") ~
        input(type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" required=true)
        textarea(name="content" rows="20" cols="100%" required=true)
        input(type="file" name="pictureFile" required=true accept="image/*")
        input(type="submit" value="submit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multer npm package it will store the file in local folder and return you the path for it and you can store the path in MySQL database